# Is it possible to enable the automatic loading of an association for products?

Tags: associations, product, shopware, storefront, shopware6

I'm looking for a way to automatically load all streams from a product when loading a product (product/category page) but can't seem to find a way to add this. I could add it as an extended attribute, but I would rather make use of the `$product->getStreams()` function.

I've tried the following but I couldn't figure out how to add an association through this method:

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
{
    return [
        ProductEvents::PRODUCT_LOADED_EVENT => 'onLoad'
    ];
}

public function onLoad(EntityLoadedEvent $event): void
{
    $product = $event->getEntities();
}
```

Comment: It depends, where do you want to load this? The PRODUCT_LOADED event is too late, as the product is already loaded here. 
You will have to search for an event which has the Criteria object used to load the products, before the query is executed. But depending on where the products you want to extend are loaded, this event is not always available.

Answer (score 2):

You could decorate the `product.repository` and alter the criteria to add the association for `streams` before calling `search` of the decorated repository. You can find an example [here](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/31cc2e763e02578d9c285130db6a85c3a612cc8e/src/Core/Content/Media/DataAbstractionLayer/MediaRepositoryDecorator.php#L144) where the `media.repository` used to be decorated to alter the search criteria before fetching the data.

Service definition:

```xml
<service id="MyPlugin\Core\Content\Product\ProductRepositoryDecorator" decorates="product.repository">
       <argument type="service" id="MyPlugin\Core\Content\Product\ProductRepositoryDecorator.inner"/>
</service>
```

In the Decorator:

```php
public function search(Criteria $criteria, Context $context): EntitySearchResult
{
    $criteria->addAssociation('streams');

    return $this->decorated->search($criteria, $context);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create your own product repository

```php
    final class SalesChannelProductRepository implements SalesChannelRepositoryInterface
    {
        /**
         * @var SalesChannelRepositoryInterface
         */
        private $repository;
    
        public function __construct(
            SalesChannelRepositoryInterface $repository
        ) {
            $this->repository = $repository;
        }
    
        public function search(Criteria $criteria, SalesChannelContext $salesChannelContext): EntitySearchResult
        {
            $this->processCriteria($criteria);
    
            return $this->repository->search($criteria, $salesChannelContext);
        }
    
        private function processCriteria(Criteria $criteria): void
        {
            $criteria->addAssociation('streams');
        }
    }
```

define service decorate default product repository

```xml
<service id="my_example.sales_channel.product.repository"
                 class="MyExample\Core\Content\Product\SalesChannel\SalesChannelProductRepository"
                 decorates="sales_channel.product.repository"
                 public="false">
            <argument type="service" id="my_example.sales_channel.product.repository.inner"/>           
        </service>
```

Comment: You still need to add every function the SalesChannelRepositoryInterface requires right? Do you just copy paste those from the product repository class?

Comment: @Alphaegen right. there are missing `aggregate` and `searchIds`. you can do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the people who reacted tho this question I've gotten to the decorated below. I'm still running into some problems related to using properties as filter in the Dynamic Product group rules. I've created a new thread for that here: [Getting streams from product returns zero results with some rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72963051/getting-streams-from-product-returns-zero-results-with-some-rules)

Decorator class:

```
class ProductRepositoryDecorator implements SalesChannelRepositoryInterface
{
    private SalesChannelRepositoryInterface $decorated;

    public function __construct(
        SalesChannelRepositoryInterface $decorated
    ) {
        $this->decorated = $decorated;
    }

    public function search(Criteria $criteria, SalesChannelContext $salesChannelContext): EntitySearchResult
    {
        $this->processCriteria($criteria);

        return $this->decorated->search($criteria, $salesChannelContext);
    }

    private function processCriteria(Criteria $criteria): void
    {
        $criteria->addAssociation('streams');
    }

    public function aggregate(Criteria $criteria, SalesChannelContext $salesChannelContext): AggregationResultCollection
    {
        return $this->decorated->aggregate($criteria, $salesChannelContext);
    }

    public function searchIds(Criteria $criteria, SalesChannelContext $salesChannelContext): IdSearchResult
    {
        return $this->decorated->searchIds($criteria, $salesChannelContext);
    }
}
```

services.xml:

```
<service id="Vendor\Base\Core\Content\Product\ProductRepositoryDecorator" decorates="sales_channel.product.repository">
        <argument type="service" id="Vendor\Base\Core\Content\Product\ProductRepositoryDecorator.inner"/>
</service>
```