# Getting streams from product returns an empty collection with some dynamic product group rules

Tags: stream, entity, associations, product, shopware

I've created a decoration which enables the automatic loading of `streams` for products. This makes me able to access the Dynamic Product groups in the storefront, but I'm running into some problems when using some rules. Everything works fine when selecting a specific product or when using the `productNumber equals number` rule, but when I try to select products based on property values it always returns an empty collection. It might be because I'm using products with variants even tho I'm inheriting the properties. The variants do show up in the `Preview` screen for a product group.

Thread in which I've added my decoration:
[Is it possible to enable the automatic loading of an association for products?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72940007/is-it-possible-to-enable-the-automatic-loading-of-an-association-for-products)

**Edit:**
I've created 2 decorations. One for the `EntityRepositoryInterface` and the other for the `SalesChannelRepositoryInterface`. Both contain a search function in which I've added the `->addAssociation('streams')`. The result is now not `null` anymore, but an empty collection in cases where the `stream` (dynamic product group) rule uses `properties` as described in the thread above. When using a specific category within the rule to filter on it does show a stream, so It's a specific problem with variant properties (probably more inherited product data).

Comment: I've tried making `streams` inherited but that completely crashes Shopware with an upstream error. Any other ideas?

Comment: did you add the property association to your criteria or tried using a equals on the ids just for testing?

Comment: I've tried using a repository outside of the decorator, adding the `->addAssociation('streams')`, but the same problem occurs.

Comment: I meant ->addAssociation('properties'), cause this might be missing since it is not auto loaded

Comment: I've tried both `->addAssociation('properties.group')` and `->addAssociation('properties')`, but nothing seems to change.